# I don't understand why string.replace correctly executes function containing a variable?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, html

At the moment I'm reading a new HTML5 book (HTML5. Webseiten innovativ und zukunftssicher by Peter Kröner). There are some examples how to teach IE6-8 to understand HTML5. One strategy looks like this (if Javascript is enabled):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>HTML5 in IE</title>
        <script>
            'abbr article aside audio canvas details figcaption
            figure footer header hgroup mark menu meter nav 
            output progress section summary time video'
            .replace(/\w+/g, function(n) {window.document.createElement(n)});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <section>
        <header>
                <h1>This is the header</h1>
        </header>
        <section>
            <h2>Chapter 1</h2>
                <p>
                Text, Text, Text, Text, Text...
                Text, Text, Text, Text, Text...
                Text, Text, Text, Text, Text...
                Text, Text, Text, Text, Text...     
                </p>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <p>
                This is the footer.
            </p>
        </footer>
     </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I open the debugger in IE, the DOM is correct. When I omit the JS-function, the DOM is broken. So this example works. 
What I don't understand is how this replace statement actually works. If I understand string.replace right, it should have had replaced the string with the function itself but obviously window.document.createElement was replaced and somehow correctly executed with each "tag", so each "tag" was parsed by the function. Why does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'abbr article aside audio'.replace(/\w+/g, function(n) { console.log(n); });
```

Produces:

```
abbr
article
aside
audio
```

---

[`.replace(regex, callback)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) will execute the callback with the match as an argument, for each match found. Your example uses this property of `.replace()` to create a dom element for every word in the string.

A semantically equivalent implementation using an `Array`:

```
var elems = ['abbr', 'article', 'aside', 'audio'];
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    window.document.createElement(elems[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that that one paramter can be a string or a function. This is the first time I see that. I recently got a new book and there is nothing written about this which makes me a little bit angry now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function as the second parameter of the `replace()` method of a string to replace the matched characters in the string. The first parameter passed to the function is the string matched by the current regex match, which in this case is each of the tag names "abbr", "article" etc., which is then passed to `window.document.createElement()`.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Example%3a_Using_an_inline_function_that_modifies_the_matched_characters) for full details.

Comment: Obviously this reference is better than the Javascript book I recently got.